# ImportError: cannot import name 'SQLAlchemy' from 'flask_sqlalchemy' (unknown location)

Tags: python, heroku, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

After successfully pushing my python app to heroku without any hiccup, I issued  `heroku ps:scale web=1` command and encountered error below in heroku logs;

```
2018-11-27T08:34:03.963364+00:00 app[web.1]: from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
2018-11-27T08:34:03.971768+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: cannot import name 'SQLAlchemy' from 'flask_sqlalchemy' (unknown location)
2018-11-27T08:34:03.972159+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-27 08:34:03 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2018-11-27T08:34:04.163955+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Despite setting up a virtual environment for sqlalchemy using the following steps/commands;

```
virtualenv sqlalchemy
source flask.ext.sqlalchemy/bin/activate
pip install sqlalchemy
deactivate

virtualenv flask_sqlalchemy
source flask_sqlalchemy/bin/activate
pip install flask-sqlalchemy
deactivate
```

With the following imports in my python code;

```
import flask_sqlalchemy
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
```

and required Heroku files;

Content of Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn project:app  --log-file - --log-level debug
```

Content of requirements.txt;

```
Flask
gunicorn
```

Content of runtime.txt;

```
python-3.7.1
```

SQLAlchemy cannot be found.

Please find my codes [here](https://github.com/jerandtze/item-catalog)

The python app runs well on local machine but not on Heroku. Is there  an appropriate way to install SQLAlchemy for proper importation? Or is there another approach to  this?

Comment: You need to add all the required packages in requirement.txt files.

Comment: Please include relevant code in the question itself, or in other words produce a [mcve]. Links may rot and the question should be self contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From heroku [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#declare-app-dependencies):

> The **requirements.txt** file lists the app dependencies together. When an app is deployed, Heroku reads this file and installs the appropriate Python dependencies using the *pip install -r command*.

Your github repo has a *requirements.txt*, but it's missing dependencies like SQLAlchemy and some other maybe you installed locally.

To save all packages you installed locally, open your command line and go to you project directory and (if you are using virtualenv, first activate that env than go to project directory using command line) and type:

> pip freeze > requirements.txt

This will save all packages you have installed locally.

Comment: Thanks Dinko! Finally got it working proper installation of dependencies.